# Is there something wrong with the questions that I asked?

Tags: discussion, questions

Yesterday I was spending a lot of time with golang for my first time, and I ended up asking three questions because I couldn't find the answers myself.

[What does an empty map of interfaces do in a golang function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793673/what-does-an-empty-map-of-interfaces-do-in-a-golang-function) [1 downvote]

[Parenthesis after a slice in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786884/parenthesis-after-a-slice-in-go) [3 upvotes | 2 downvotes]

[Are pointers dereferenced by default in golang struct methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786206/are-pointers-dereferenced-by-default-in-golang-struct-methods) [1 downvote]

Normally when I ask a bad question, I'm able to recognize that and delete it, but I don't see the problem with these. Could someone explain why they should/shouldn't be downvoted?

Am I missing something?

Comment: *"Normally when I ask a bad question, I'm able to recognize that and delete it,"*, editing them into a good question is a better option when possible. Apart from that, your first two seem to not show much effort or explanation. The last one seems ok to me (note: I've never dealt with GO).

Comment: I don't know Go at all (so I'd be happy to be corrected by someone who does) but your questions might be very basic. The downvote button says "Does not show any research effort" -- could your questions by answered by a bit more study of a standard Go tutorial? I'd say your questions are presented clearly enough, but they do appear to be fairly basic, so that gives me some concern that they may be *too* basic, and people who regularly hang out in the `[go]` questions don't care for it. (Or, really, at minimum *one or two* people don't care for it, and the rest are apathetic.)

Comment: @apsillers I'd be careful with the word "basic". Yes, a lot of people do downvote because they think it is basic. But that shouldn't matter. If the question is detailed well enough then being basic for some shouldn't attract downvotes (again, they still sometimes do).

Comment: @apsillers I agree that the first was rather basic since it involved me not knowing understanding what interface{} does, but for the other two, they weren't really in tutorials. It involved the experienced users digging through the language specification, which I don't think would be reasonable to expect of me as a beginner (Although I will eventually be learning that spec).

Comment: It seems like the golang community on stackoverflow aggressively downvotes questions from neophytes, regardless of their appropriateness. It's true, many of them can be answered by a thorough review of the standard documentation; however, it seems that many askers are so new as to not understand how to read the documentation adequately.

Answer (score 2):

If you've exhausted any reasons you can think of why it should be improved and downvoters haven't left comments, there's limited options. You can ask in a comment why you're being downvoted and what should be improved (which might work, if a downvoter visits your question again) or you can look over your questions and see if there's a pattern to them.

For instance, did you notice that two of your questions there were answered by quoting the spec? Maybe you don't spend enough time reading up the official documentation on these tools before asking questions. Not properly consulting the basic instruction manual is worthy of a downvote as lacking effort to some people.

Comment: *"You can ask in a comment why you're being downvoted"* - I think that this is a waste of time; if people want to comment with their downvotes they can already, and it's unlikely that a previous downvoter will check back to see if the OP wants to know why, so any subsequent comments tend to be *"I am not the downvoter [may or may not be a lie!] but they might have downvoted because..."*